# Sharing a keyboard and mouse between networked computers

Tags: networking, keyboard, share, mouse

What software is out there that allows a mouse and keyboard to be shared between 2+ networked computers?

I know about [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/), but what are the alternatives? Which do you like the best?

I'm personally most interested in something compatible with both Mac OS X and Windows, but software that is limited to certain platforms is still of interest, so please mention it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried some, but was never more satisfied as with [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

**Teleport** is a free software for Mac OSX:

http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/

It isn't compatible with Windows though. It works only between Macs.

---

**Multiplicity** for Windows:

http://www.stardock.com/products/multiplicity/

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(software)):

> Multiplicity comes in two versions,
>   the standard Multiplicity and
>   Multiplicity Pro. The standard version
>   has all the above features, including
>   the ability to copy and paste images
>   and text between computers. The Pro
>   version also allows the user to
>   control up to six client computers as
>   well as the ability to copy and paste
>   files, folders, and other data between
>   machines.
>
> (...) A
>   Mac OS X client is in development, due
>   in part to the popularity of the Mac
>   mini. A Linux client is reportedly
>   planned, but has not yet been
>   developed.

Answer (score 2):

[Input director](http://rbytes.net/software/input-director-review/) is pretty good

Answer (score 1):

http://kavoom.biz/ is highly recommended by those who use it, but it is Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using Remote desktop for windows machines, any VNC client can be used quite easily for linux / unix machines however if you want distinct sessions for users [XManager](http://www.netsarang.com/products/xmg_detail.html) works really well (although is not OSS)

Answer (score 0):

XMing http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming works well if you are connecting to any XWindows system from MS Windows.